# javscript Ternary operator if json value is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return false if null is returned, but it keeps returning true even when it returns null.

hello.json.

```
{
  "hello": null
}

or 

{
 "hello" : {
    id: 1,
    hi: 'hi'
   } 
}
```

```
console.log(hello === null ? false : true)
```

The hello value is output as a null value and I want to return false. What should I do?

`console.log((hello === null ? 'false' : 'true'))`

If hello is null, I expected false to come out, but it came out true.

Comment: It should be `myObj.hello`. Whatever that `hello` is inside the `console.log` is most likely not the value of the object's property.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass obj.key

```js
obj = {
 "hello" : null
}
console.log(obj.hello === null ? false : true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(YourObject.hello) {
 return true;
}
else{ 
 return false; 
}
```

Using **ternary** operator

```
console.log((YourObject.hello) ? true : false);
```

will evaluate to true if the value is not:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

Comment: When I use the ternary operator it always returns true .

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object, but accessing it wrong, you need to access the object's value like this:

```
obj = {
 "hello" : null
}
obj.hello === null ? false : true
```

Comment: When I use the ternary operator it always returns true .

Comment: because you are accessing the object wrongly